# In Excel , how to reference a cell with more than one character in its column name in a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a sheet in a workbook where formulas in cells refer to cells on another worksheet in an absolute fashion.

This works as long as the column name is <= Z. For AA or greater the formula seems to be saved as text instead of executing.

Example:

This works:

`=IF(Extract!$Z2<>0,Extract!$Z2,"N/A")`

This Doesn't

`=IF(Extract!$AA2<>0,Extract!$AA2,"N/A")`

Thoughts?

**Update**

Turns out that copying the formula into the cell and then editing it is the problem. Typing it in directly works. This wasn't a problem in previous cases. FWIW, cel format doesn't seem to be the issue; the same cell worked or didn't depending on the formula. That said, incorrect format can cause issues. The hunt for the exact problem continues.

Thanks for our comments.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you provided. Your exact formula works here with no issues.

Comment: Make sure the cell formats in columns AA and beyond are set to `General` and not `Text`.

Comment: Issue updated. Doesn't seem to be column name specific...

Comment: Is this a Table format in reference Worksheet?

Comment: @Lee nope. This seems to happen sporadically after the formula is copied into a different cell and edited. I've had it happen for single character columns now. Previously it happened when changing from a single to dual character column name. I'm just typing manually until it "sticks" at this point.